# Finding the Taylor series representation for $\frac{1}{1-z}\quad |z|>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm tasked with finding the Taylor series representation for $\frac{1}{1-z}\quad |z|>1$ from $\frac{1}{1-z}\quad |z|<1$ where the following hint is provided

$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{-1}{z(1-\frac{1}{z})}$$

I don't recognize a way to proceed immediately - advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you asked seems to be **Laurent series**. If $|z|>1$, then $1/|z|<1$. Using
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots,\quad(|x|<1)
$$
we get
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=-\frac{1/z}{1-(1/z)}=-\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n.
$$

Comment: Oh wow, I see it now. However, what happened to your negative sign in the last step?

Comment: Oops, I forgot the negative sign. I edited my post.